# How to extract and pass exif data (array) using exif() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a photo stock system and want to extract `exif()` data of images that users add. I am not sure how to pass the array of `exif()` into database and then display that data in view. For that I have created a row as `string(p_exif)` in the migration. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried passing data in array but it seems to not work.

I initially ran this code to save image on my project folder:

```
Image::make($image)->resize(640,390)->save($location);
```

Later to extract exif data, I ran this code:

```
$data = Image::make($image)->resize(640,390)->save($location)->exif();
```

But it seems I am making a mistake here that I'm not being able to figure out. I am not sure how to pass the array `$data` into the database and then to view.

I want to store `exif()` data array in the database. The error says something about not passing arrays.

Comment: When does the program say "The error says something about not passing arrays." ? Could you show the code which trigger this error ?

Comment: The error says ErrorException (E_NOTICE) 'Array to string conversion'.
I tried doing this when I encountered the error:
`$data = Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(640,390)->save($large_image_path)->exif();`
`$img->p_exif = $data;`

Comment: then can't you loop on the array and use multiple times your function ? with a common unique ID on them to save them in the database ?

Comment: Yes! Tried that and it worked. I wasn't sure which unique ID to use but I found some default values of `exif()` which I needed and hence used on the multiple functions. Thanks for your time!